# Rails: uninitialized constant (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, railstutorial.org

I am stuck in Chapter 11 of the Rails tutorial ("Section 11.2.5 A working follow button with Ajax"). I am getting

```
relationships_controller_spec.rb:3:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant RelationshipsController (NameError)
```

Here is my controller spec (/sample_app/spec/controllers/relationships_controller_spec.rb) The error complains about line 3:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe RelationshipsController do
let(:user) {FactoryGirl.create(:user)}
let(:other_user) {FactoryGirl.create(:user)}

before {sign_in user, no_capybara: true}

describe "create a relationship with Ajax" do

it "should increment the Relationship count" do
  expect do
    xhr :post, :create, relationship: { followed_id: other_user.id}
  end.to change(Relationship, :count).by(1)
end

it "should respond with success" do
  xhr :post, :create, relationship: {followed_id: other_user.id}
  expect(response).to be_success
end
end

describe "destroying a relationship with Ajax" do

before {user.follow!(other_user)}

let(:relationship) do
  user.relationships.find_by(followed_id: other_user.id)
end

it "should decrement the Relationship count" do
  expect do
    xhr :delete, :destroy, id: relationship.id
  end.to change(relationship, :count).by(-1)
end

it "should respond with success" do
  xhr :delete, :destroy, id: relationship.id
  expect(response).to be_success
end
end
end
```

Here is the controller (/sample_app/app/controllers/relatonships_controller.rb) itself:

```
class RelationshipsController < ApplicationController
before_action :signed_in_user

def create
@user = User.find(params[:relationship][:followed_id])
current_user.follow!(@user)
#redirect_to @user replaced with the code below:
respond_to do |format|
  format.html {redirect_to @user}
  format.js
end
end

def destroy
@user = Relationship.find(params[:id]).followed
current_user.unfollow!(@user)
#redirect_to @user replaced with the code below:
respond_to do |format|
  format.html {redirect_to @user}
  format.js
end
end
end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you spell the name of the controller file correctly? `app/controllers/relationships_controller.rb`. I suspect that perhaps you left off the last "r?"

Comment: @Chris Peters This must have been a typo when I wrote the post. I now added the 'r' to the error message above. So, unfortunately, the problem does not seem to be due to the file name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in the filename: /relatonships, no i between relat and onships.

Answer (score 0):

What are your filenames? In Rails this can be important. Make sure your controller is actually called `relationships_controller.rb`.

It's common to maybe call either the filename or the class the singular form and the other the plural form, but it seems like something is missing an 'r'. Like your filename is `relationships_controlle.rb` somehow.

Comment: Thanks - but this seems to be a typo in my post. The error message includes the 'r'. I corrected the post. I am still having the problem though.

Comment: Actually, you have another typo in the filename: /relatonships, no i between relat and onships.

Comment: @frandroid: yes, this was the reason - thanks! If you put this in a separate post I'll accept t.